# Parse backend new Error for uploading files - Error: File name must be a string - PFFile

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm building an IOS app and using parse.com as a backend. All of a sudden, today I am getting this error - Error: File name must be a string without any other explanation. I'm certain the file name that I am using is a string. I haven't changed any of the Native IOS code so it must be a new Parse issue. The only difference - today I updated my account to the new pricing model on Parse, wondering if that's related?

```
// Code snippet 
NSString *fileName = @"test.mov"; // Also tried just @"test"

PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:fileName data:fileData]; // NSData - 286553 bytes

[file saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
// Break point right here - this is where the error occurs.
```

Comment: @Fogmeister, just ran another app I built that uploads files to my Parse account. Same exact error out of the blue.

Comment: Cool. But still without code we can do nothing. I have a parse app that I wrote a while back and I also am uploading PFFiles and I too switched to the new pricing plan today and I am not getting this crash. There must be something in your code that is causing this.

Comment: Damn. Just posted a code snippet. You think it's something to do with the data I've uploaded already?

Comment: Interestingly, https://www.parse.com/questions/new - Asking a new question right now is down on Parse.com

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but I'm experiencing similar issues.  After reading this (I already upgraded) I checked my app (released in appstore) and found that I was getting crashes on File uploads.  I'm now in the process of going through the code, and its showing error on file upload, but only on parse's end.  It passes the block with success, then throws an error internally that upload failed.

Comment: @kevin - it's probably getting overwhelmed if this is happening to everyone.

Comment: @Logan - is your error happening right after completion of the save in block? I'm pointing a break point as shown in my code and the NSError isn't event getting called on my block.

Comment: Seriously reconsidering using Parse. Seems like they have major bugs pretty frequently.

Comment: Yes, the error doesn't get called in the block, it runs as successful, but the file isn't saved (i get a print out from parse internally of the failed upload).  This means my code gets served a success block without a successful save.  Errors galore.  I was using my app perfectly yesterday, just upgraded, and everything is crashing.

Comment: I just realized, it was outputting upload failed error code 100.  I looked it up and it's the string error you mention.  I'm really glad I saw this question before I spent hours agonizing over my code.  I think its safe to say that this is a major bug on Parse's and something is going on that needs to be fixed immediately.

Comment: Just reported the bug here - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1420998118170390/

Comment: I also posted it on their release blog here - http://blog.parse.com/2014/04/30/parse-pricing-now-cheaper-and-simpler/

Comment: @Logan - the error in my subject line is actually referring to when the file doesn't succeed and then I try to save it to a PFObject, so I get the 100 Error code and then the 111 Error code

Comment: Can you provide the link? You mean on http://blog.parse.com/

Comment: Found it http://blog.parse.com/2014/04/30/parse-pricing-now-cheaper-and-simpler/

Comment: https://www.parse.com/questions/pffile-uploads-are-not-working-after-updating-to-the-new-pricing-today

Answer (score 1):

**NEWS:**

ALL should go to: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/622479264497355/?comment_id=1426426400945705

### And post your account email to Hector Ramos.

**Update2:**
This has been fixed and is preparing for a deploy.

**The problem is:** Basically, if you are currently using LESS than 1GB of data storage (for example, I'm using 679MB), instead of correctly calculating that I'm using (679 / (1024MB * 20)) = 3.3% of the quota, its calculating it as 679/20, which gets the result of 3395%.  Parse, if you see this, PLEASE... its really just a few lines of code.. please resolve this ASAP!

Comment: how'd you come to that conclusion?

Comment: It seems to be calculating on 20MB instead of 20GB, i'm using about 14MBs and the Parse Performance tab got: "70.5% 14.1/20GB"

Answer (score 0):

This was an internal error and has been resolved. Parse posted an incident report [here](http://status.parse.com/incidents/mvg0rsjcz6l1).

EDIT: As several people have pointed out, the error is still present even though Parse claims it has been resolved. Hrmmmmmm...

Comment: As of 6:55 PST, it is still broken for me.

Comment: The fact that it's updated as resolved is actually even more scary. Still not working for me

Comment: Crap this is holiday.. and now?

Comment: https://www.parse.com/questions/pffile-uploads-are-not-working-after-updating-to-the-new-pricing-today

Comment: anyone hv a email support or phone number?